# Sequelize Postgres value in raw SQL always throw syntax error during migration

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

I've tried double quotes, single quotes, escaped quotes, no quotes, around the values in the CASE, but each time I run the migration there is a `syntax error at or near "'example'"`

```
'use strict';

module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return Promise.resolve()
      // ... Removed for brevity
      .then(() => queryInterface
        .addColumn(...)
      )
      .then(() =>
        Sequelize.sequelize.query(
          'UPDATE TableName SET TableName.status=CASE ' +
          'WHEN TableName.status_old IS \'example\' THEN \'example2\' ' +
          'ELSE TableName.status_old END'
        )
      )
      .then(() => queryInterface
        .addColumn(...)
      );
  },

  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    // ... Removed for brevity
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `IS`, PostgreSQL doesn't know what that it is. You want a simple `=` comparison:

```
'UPDATE TableName SET TableName.status=CASE ' +
'WHEN TableName.status_old = \'example\' THEN \'example2\' ' +
'ELSE TableName.status_old END'
```